# how to set alarm in qt

Tags: qt-creator

how to set alarm in qt mobile application using the Calendar or Alarm Apis
I have seached many more but didn't find any thing.
If any body know plz help me out as i have seen That qt support calendar api nad alarm api but i didn't got anything about api to download

Answer (score 2):

There is Qt Mobility API that probably is the one you are looking for. It contain Organizer API that was previously known as Calendar API

Qt Mobility can be found [Here](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-addons/mobility)

Also API documentation of Organizer can be found [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0/organizer.html)